# Upper bound for the variance of an output neuron of a neural network

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, variance, neural-networks

Modern neural networks oftentimes apply the softmax operation to their output neurons which is defined by

$$s(x)_i = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^N e^{x_j}}$$

Here, $i$ is the index of an output neuron, and $N$ represents the total number of output neurons. That means that the sum of all output activations sum up to 1 and that the value of each output neuron lies between 0 and 1:

$$\sum_{j=1}^N s(x)_i = 1$$
$$0 \leq s(x)_i \leq 1$$

Given the information above and that the network's internal process contains some kind of randomness (dropout, random noise), is it possible to derive an upper bound of an output neuron's variance if you would predict $n$ times?

Comment: Using only the fact that $0 \le \sigma(x)_i \le 1$ one can show that the variance of $\sigma(x)_i$ is $\le 1/4$ (e.g., using [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances)). You may be able to improve this with the other information you have. More generally, it is difficult to say anything without further assumptions on the "some kind of randomness."

Comment: @angryavian By randomness I mean operations like dropout or added random noise. What do you mean by improve? Does $\sigma(x)_i \leq 1/4$ not always hold?

Comment: You asked for an upper bound on the variance, and the result I cited guarantees that the [probabilistic] variance (which the sample variance over $n$ trials approximates) is at most $1/4$. With more information you may be able to improve this upper bound (e.g., variance is at most $1/8$).

Comment: improve means that $\sigma<\alpha$, where $\alpha<1/4$ with your own efforts.

Comment: @angryavian I just realized that I used $\sigma(x)_i$ for the softmax function and is not to be confused with the variance $\sigma(x_i)$. I therefore changed the variable names of the softmax function to $s(x)_i$. I would like to know if your comment still holds, that $\sigma(x_i) \leq 1/4$?

Comment: Read my comments carefully: I do not say anything about a bound on $s(x)_i$ itself, only about the **variance** of $s(x)_i$, that is, $\text{Var}(s(x)_i)) \le 1/4$.